# Proxy bypass for podman containers inside same network

Tags: proxy, podman

Is there any way to make podman containers ignore proxy for rest calls to other podman containers hosted in the same podman network?

I tried with adding the proxy variables like (http_proxy,https_proxy and no_proxy) inside [containers] section in containers.conf file but I was facing the issue that inter-container rest api calls were also going through the proxy and were getting blocked.All the containers were under a single network so I tried giving the subnet address of the network in no_proxy but it also didnt work (maybe because we are using hostnames instead of ip addresses in the code).

Also the list of containers is not fixed so I cannot add all the container names in no_proxy.
eg: There can be 2 new containers deployed one after the other say A and B.Now A does not have the knowledge that whether B/C/D.. will come i.e the host-name can be anything but any rest call from A to B/C/D.. should ignore proxy.can it be done provided all of them are within the same network?